# Handling ajax file uploads server side with Pyramid

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, pyramid

I have an Ajax file upload with this code:

```
$('#photo-input:file').change(function() {
                var photo = this.files[0];
                var caption = $('.photo-caption').val();
                type = photo.type;
                if (photo.type != 'image/png' && photo.type != 'image/jpg' && !photo.type != 'image/gif' && photo.type != 'image/jpeg' ) {
                    alert('Sorry, you may only upload png, jpg, jpeg, or gif images.');
                    return false;
                }

                $('.photo-post-submit').click(function () {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('photo', photo);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/post',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {'photo' : formData, 'caption' : caption},
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function () {
                        }
                    }, 'json');
                });

            });
```

But when I call `request.POST['caption']` or `request.POST['photo']` I get the error:

```
Not an HTML form submission (Content-Type: application/xml)
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if you got confused between the `$.post` and `$.ajax` methods, since you are passing in a separate `json` argument (which `$.ajax` doesn't accept as a dataType argument).

Moreover, you really should not set the `contentType` to `false`, *and* you are setting `processData` to `false`, making for a very confusing mix as to what Pyramid will have to do with whatever jQuery makes of that combination.

To POST to a server with the `cache` parameter set to `false`, use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/post',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'photo' : formData, 'caption' : caption},
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

Note that the `dataType` is set to `json`, which means your Pyramid view needs to *return* JSON, the jQuery AJAX code is expecting a JSON response.

Comment: Ah, I see. That fixed the problem immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For file upload use JQuery .upload plugin.
for more details check https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin.